# github commit doesn't show up on remote server

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I have been working on a github branch (let's call it test branch) related to a C# project in my local machine, but now I have to run this code on a remote server.

Today after updating from master and committing the changes to the test branch, I connected to the server, switched to the test branch, synced the code, and the commits I have made today didn't show up on the github desktop for windows.

What am I missing, or doing wrong?

Comment: Did you merge your test branch with master before syncing?

Comment: So you:
1. made changes to the test branch on your desktop
2. git commit followed by git push
3. login to server
4. git checkout test branch
5. git pull

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski I updated the test branch from master branch. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Dave I am using the desktop version on windows, I don't even know how to use those commands. But I found out that the problem is that I haven't pushed today's commits by looking at the fork tree. And I have no idea why the sync button is not doing a push